# Зачем нужно обнуление переменных?

Tags: массивы, c

Для чего нужно обнулить массивы после объявления и константы.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c - '0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == 'n' || c == 't')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits=");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf("white space = %d, other =%dn", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Дело в том, что не могу никак для себя пояснить вот этот момент

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i] = 0;
```

Для чего мы пересчитываем ячейчки массива от 1 до 10, а затем еще их обнуляем? И разве не надо было объявить массив на 11 переменных, так как одна ячейка зарезервирована под ноль? Сама программа взята из Кернигана и Ричи и занимается подсчетом цифр.

Comment: Приведите пример, а то не очень понятно.

Comment: Далеко не всегда нужно обнулять массивы, а про константы я вообще не понял.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос яснее. Если подразумевается необхожимость явной инициализации переменных и массивов, так это потому что в противном случае они будут заполнены случайными значениями. Причем дебаг и релиз версии программ могут из-за этого вести себя по-разному. В дебаг-версиях обычно все массивы и переменные инитятся нулями. Но рассчитывать на это я не стал бы.

Comment: Обнулять константы? это как?

Другими словами - нужен код

Comment: Надо думать минусов накидали за первый вариант вопроса

    Для чего нужно обнулить массивы после объявления и константы

и все...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[gecube](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/907/gecube) верно говорит в комментарии, С это не C# и Java, никто кроме вас не будет обнулять значения в массиве. Когда вы выделяете память под массив, то вы выделяете просто диапазон адресов, а что было(что находится) в этих ячейках памяти никто не знает, никто не знает, что за программа использовала этот участок памяти до этого. В этом коде обнуление проводится для того, чтобы вести подсчет повторений каждой цифры в веденной строке, т.е. на выходе в **ndigit[3]** будет количество троек в **ndigit[6]** количество шестерок. Обнулять нужно из-за этой конструкции **++ndigit[c - '0'];** чтобы не было какого-нибудь -3267.

Answer (score 51):

На тему вопроса есть классический программерский анекдот:

> У Пети было 3 яблока, два он дал Маше. Сколько яблок стало у Маши?
>
> Думаете два? Нет, не верно. Мы же не знаем, сколько у нее было яблок до этого.

Вывод — перед присваиванием переменные нужно инициализировать, чтобы знать начальное значение. Обнуление — частный случай инициализации, не более.

Comment: Эм.. Не перед присваиванием, а перед считыванием.

Answer (score 6):

Ну на самом деле всё не так, а вернее не так плоско. Допустим mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS) даёт уже занулёные страницы, и очень потешно, когда 95% их зануляют для надёжности. Маллок на больших кусках так же юзает ммап, и занулять память не надо. Но сколько бы я не гледял - все тупо юзают мемсет для надёжности.

Вобщем наверное проще юзать мемсет, либо занулять как в примере "для надёжности", во избежание всяких граблей.

Comment: @o2n3e, как думаете calloc() без нужды memset() будет вызывать?

Я к тому, что может Вы исходники смотрели (мне обычно лень).

Comment: Никогда не юзал calloc(). Думаю, что в гну не идиоты и попусту он мемсет не юзает.

Answer (score 2):

Просто до первого приращения `++ndigit` в ячейках находится мусор ну например число 12560. а вам нужно приращение от нуля

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к неинициализированному объекту — это даже не unspecified, а undefined behaviour. Так делать нельзя, и компилятор по стандарту имеет право сгенерировать код, который удалит вашу базу данных и передаст ваши деньги афганским хакерам.

То есть там не просто «непонятно какое значение». Оптимизатор имеет право предполагать, что доступа к неинициализированной переменной быть не может в принципе, и удалить любой кусок кода вокруг. То, что проблем до этого не было, — чистая случайность.

Примеры: [[1]](http://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/), [[2]](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: Правда, static переменные сам компилятор инициализирует нулями.

Еще, в Linux "свежие" страницы, возвращаемые ядром (впервые получаемые процессом) тоже обнулены.

Comment: @avp: Свежие страницы — да. Но локальная переменная в функции скорее всего будет на стеке, а он чаще всего уже выделен.

Кроме того, можно вполне нарваться на trap representation (например, [Not A Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx)).

Comment: @VladD, да -- "свежие страницы" -- это информация, которой практически невозможно воспользоваться.

Вообще-то  их обнуление это в какой-то мере бредовая идея, которую в свое время реализовали, чтобы успокоить параноидальных безопасников.

Comment: @avp: Я вот думаю — почему в стандарте не сделали автоинициализацию переменных нулями? Если переменной сразу после этого присваивается значение, ненужную инициализацию выкинет оптимизатор.

Обратную совместимость это, по идее, не нарушит, а вот целый класс UB исчез бы.

Хотя, есть ещё memory-mapped-переменные на embedded-платформах, туда лишняя запись катастрофична.

Comment: Ещё как нарушит. Есть целая пачка паттернов, которые это используют. Я лично встречал такое (ответ предлагается угадать, потом компилировать без оптимизаций и снова угадать. Да, я знаю, что подобный код - это очень сильный трэш, но в микроконтроллерах подобное иногда используется)

    #include <stdio.h>

    void set(int a)
    {
        int b;
        b = a;
    }

    void print()
    {
        int b;
        printf("b = %d", b);
    }

    int main(void) {
        set(100);
        print();
        return 0;
    }

Comment: @KoVadim: Этот код полагается на UB. Запустите его под valgrind'ом, он крешнется. Полагаться на UB с выключенными оптимизациями — прямой путь к катастрофе. Завтра компилятор за-spill-ит переменную в регистр (имеет полное право), и весь код полетит.

---
Но да, я согласен: многие пользуются ужасным кодом, полагаясь не на стандарт, а на особенности кодогенерации своего компилятора.

И это очень печально.

Comment: я прекрасно знаю, на что он полагается. И нормальном коде подобное недопустимо. Но в среде микроконтроллеров - иногда есть смысл (когда экономится каждый такт и бит.

Comment: @KoVadim, моей первой мыслью было -- напечатает адрес фрейма (начала локальных переменных) main.

Но потом я проверил gcc 4.8.2 в 32-bit Xubuntu и ...

Посмотрел в gdb и gcc -S и сильно удивился, что смещение `b` в `set()` -- `-4(%ebp)`, а в `print()` -- `-12(%ebp)` (в обеих функциях, естественно `ebp` одинаков (`movl %esp, %ebp` в прологе)).

--

А Вы что предполагали напечатать?

Comment: у меня печатает, как и ожидалось b=100. проверил на clang (version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)) - также нормально отработало. Но если дописать хотя бы -O1 - все, валится, печатает мусор.

На gcc (version 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1) (GCC)) точно также.

Насколько я знаю, gcc умеет подтягивать дополнительный конфиг с /etc. А там мало чего может быть прописано.

Comment: Посмотрел в 64-bit Ubuntu (тот же  gcc 4.8.2), да, печатает 100.

Довольно естественно, поскольку известно, что в этой архитектуре аргументы в функции передаются в регистрах.

--

Между прочим, совершенно не понимаю, почему при передаче аргументов в стеке, Вы ожидаете, что `b` в `set(int a)` и `b` в `print()` будут расположены по одному и тому же адресу?

--

Похоже, последний коммент здесь, так что пообсуждать не смогу...

Comment: А фишка в том, что компиляторы не только пытаются оптимизировать всё что можно, но и содержат фильтры на признаки нарушений и стараются на них реагировать полояльнее. Так clang вводит понятие неизвестного объекта и смотрит на явные приведения указателей. Рассчёт идёт на то, что если undefined behaviour допускается случайно (или просто случай очень распространённый), то это сможет как-то помочь. Поэтому и работало.

Comment: @Glorfindel It seems that your new script breaks some links (see the edit history)

Comment: @VladD thanks a lot for catching that (and for pinging me). It's definitely something the script should be able to handle correctly, I'll have a look how I can improve it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Maybe you can use codereview.SE for this?

Comment: @VladD that's only for reviewing working code, this is definitely a bug :)