# Что тут не так с переменными (С)? (их значения равны, хотя не должны)

Tags: c, visual-studio, указатели, время

Добрый день. Пишу лабораторную на тему стека. Я хочу, чтобы считывались данные из файла (это расписание) и считалась разница между соседними значениями времени. Но почему то в отладке даже при  пустом стеке (когда stackOfTrains.count == 0) tmFinish равен tmStart! (хотя его значение задается только при считывании каждой строки или внутри цикла при непустом стеке). Что тут не так, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Файл для считывания shedule.txt:

```
12 10.01
14 10.15
11 10.08
```

Мой код:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h> 
//#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <fstream> 
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <time.h>


struct Stack
{
    int A[255][3];
    int count;
};

//проверка стека на пустоту

int isEmpty(struct Stack *p)
{
    if (p -> count ==0 ) return 1;
    else if ( p->count == 255) return -1;
    else return 0;
}


void pushIntoStek(struct Stack *p, int elem[3])  // включение в стек
{
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <3; j++){
        p -> A[p -> count][j] = elem[j];
    }

    p -> count++;
}

int *returnLastElem(struct Stack *p)  // возвращение последнего элемента
{
    return p -> A[(p -> count) - 1];
}

int  deleteFromStek(struct Stack *p)             // удаление из стека
{
    if (isEmpty(p) == 1) return -1;
    else {
        p -> count--;
        return 0;
    }
}


void printStek(struct Stack *p)            // вывод содержимого стека на экран
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if (p -> count == 0) {
        printf("Stek is empty\n");
    }
    else { 
        for (i = 0; i< p -> count; i++){ 
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                printf("%d ",p -> A[i][j]);
            }
    }  
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main(){

        char* nameOfFileInput = "shedule.txt";
        FILE *fileInput = NULL;
        char str[255];  
        char* strCur = NULL;
        int i;
        int numOfString = 0;
        char firstWord[30], otherString[30];
        int firstWordLen = 0, otherStringLen = 0;
        char *space;
        int isDig = 1;
        struct tm *tmStart, *tmFinish;
        int *last;
        int train[3] ;//номер; часы, минуты
        struct Stack stackOfTrains;
        double dfTime;
        time_t timeFirst, timeLast, t;
        stackOfTrains.count = 0;

        timeFirst = time(NULL); 
        timeLast = time(NULL);
        t = time(NULL);



        for (i = 0; i<255; i++){
            str[i] = "";
        }                
        do {
            isDig = 1;

            printf("Input a time of waiting\n");
            gets(str);                  
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
               if  (isdigit(str[i]) == 0 )
                    isDig = 0;
            } 
            if (isDig == 0) printf("The entered value must be a number! \n");
        }
        while (isDig == 0);

        fileInput = fopen( nameOfFileInput, "r" );
        if(fileInput == NULL){
            printf("Can't oprn a file '%s'",nameOfFileInput);
            return 2;
        } 

         while( !feof(fileInput) ) {      
         strCur = fgets(str,255,fileInput);
         if (strCur == NULL){                  
             printf ("\nError reading of file \n");//ERROR
             break;
          }

         tmStart = localtime(&t);
         tmFinish = localtime(&t);
         sscanf(str, "%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &train[0], &train[1], &train[2]);
         //printf("%s %d %d %d \n", str, train[0], train[1], train[2]);


         tmStart -> tm_min = train[2];//то, что содержится в текущей строке
         tmStart -> tm_hour = train[1];

         if ( stackOfTrains.count > 0){                      
            last = returnLastElem(&stackOfTrains);

            tmFinish -> tm_min = last[2];//то, что содержится в стеке последняя запись
            tmFinish -> tm_hour = last[1];

            timeFirst = mktime(tmStart);
            timeLast = mktime(tmFinish);    
            dfTime = difftime(timeLast,timeFirst);
            //printf("$d %s %s %s %f\n", stackOfTrains.count, ":::", asctime(tmStart), asctime(tmFinish), dfTime);
         }
         pushIntoStek( &stackOfTrains, train);

         getch();

        }
        fclose(fileInput);
        printStek(&stackOfTrains)  ; 
        getch();
}
```

Comment: мне кажется, что Вам поможет мой ответ на один очень древний [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155912/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/170022#170022)

Comment: добавила после объявления переменных 
tmStart = localtime(&t);
        tmFinish = localtime(&t); не помогло. Почему то в каждом цикле считывания из файла они оказываются равны.

Answer (score 2):

Оказывается, тут дело в 
tmStart = localtime(&t); 
tmFinish = localtime(&t);
Использование localtime возвращает ссылку всегда на один и тот же участок памяти, поэтому изменение одной из этих переменных автоматически меняло и другую.