# функция gai_strerror вызывает ошибку сегментирования

Tags: c, сеть, dns

вот программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo * ip;
    if (argc != 2) {
         printf("пожалуйста, укажите ТОЛЬКО ipv4-адрес в первом аргументе");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int ec = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, NULL, &ip);
    if (ec != 0)
        printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ec));

    return 0;
}
```

при вводе неправильного адреса вместо сообщения об ошибке - ошибка сегментирования, что я сделал не так?

да и предупреждения о неявной декларации функций gai_strerror и getaddrinfo неплохо бы починить... почему gcc их выдает?

Comment: ` if (argc > 2)` - т.е. аргумент командной строки должен быть один, или не быть ни одного?

Comment: @Harry один... но это к основной ошибке не относится.

Comment: Да, об основной я ничего не писал. Просто в глаза бросилось.

Comment: Очень интересно. У меня `Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` все работает (и компилируется даже с -Wall без сообщений) / У вас какая ОС?

Comment: Кстати, в аргументе можно передавать не только ipv4, но и ipv6 адрес, а также и имя хоста (например, `ru.stackoverflow.com`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user232384, действительно с -std=c99 не компилируется.

А падает (в 64-bit системе), вот почему.

Смотрите:

```
...
t.c:17:37: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ec));
                                     ^
t.c:17:16: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ec));
```

Обратите внимание на второй warning.

Т.е. компилятор считает, что `gai_strerror()` возвратит `int` (**32 бита!!!**) и передает в `printf` не тот правильный адрес сообщения, который возвращает `gai_strerror()`, а его младшие 32 бита вместе с **необнуленными** старшими 32-мя битами в регистре `%rsi`.

**Вот `printf` и падает**, когда пытается взять байты по кривому адресу.

---

Для `getaddrinfo` и др. требуется, чтобы выражение

```
_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

было истинно.

Почему с -std=c99 `Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` + `gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609` это не так, не знаю.

P.S.

Если вам действительно необходимо компилировать с -std=c99 (или -std=c11), то можно просто самому добавить правильные прототипы

```
#if !(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE)
int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                       const struct addrinfo *hints,
                       struct addrinfo **res);
const char *gai_strerror(int errcode);
#endif
```

(а для работы с результатом вставить и описание самой структуры)

```
struct addrinfo {
  int              ai_flags;
  int              ai_family;
  int              ai_socktype;
  int              ai_protocol;
  socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
  struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
  char            *ai_canonname;
  struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
```

из [man getaddrinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)

Answer (score 1):

Я уже когда-то писал ответ на вопрос - [Зачем нужно инициализировать переменные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155912/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/170022#170022). В Вашем примере эта же ошибка. Дело в том, что ip будет указывать на мусор ("в неведомые дали"). `getaddrinfo` посмотри, поймет, что указатель не нулевой и не будет выделять память и по указанному адресу запишет результат... А дальше кто его знает. Может так окажется, что это "доступная память" и все хорошо. А может и нет. Тут никто не знает, где именно "выстрелит". У меня сработало, как только я добавил в самый конец вызов `freeaddrinfo(ip);`, что бы освободить память...

Comment: ну поставил я `freeaddrinfo(ip);` перед return, та же самая ошибка сегментирования...

Comment: а переменную занулить? `struct addrinfo * ip = NULL;` А условие `if (argc != 1) {` исправить на `if (argc != 2) {`

Comment: я занулил, все равно та же  картина, а условие исправил ещё до этого...

Comment: очень интересно. Но давайте найдем причину. компилируем так `gcc -ggdb код.с`. Дальше запускаем `gdb ./a.out` и потом, уже в gdb `run test` (где test - это параметр). Когда оно "упадет", пишем `bt` и смотрим стектрейс. Как минимум будет понятно, в каком именно месте падает.

Comment: Очень интересно. У меня `Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` все работает. Обнуление переменной тут вообще ни при чем. Я экспериментировал с инициализацией заведомо неверным адресом и никаких ошибок. Впрочем это ожидаемо, поскольку `getaddrinfo` заносит адрес первого элемента списка адресов (структур `addrinfo`, связанных через поле `.ai_next`) в эту переменную. Если IP (имя хоста) неправильное, то эта переменная не меняется.

Comment: все работает без -std=c99, я с -std=c99 компилировал...

Comment: хотя это очень странно и непредсказуемо,
@KoVadim, что это?