# В чем ошибка? Можно ли вообще использовать такую структуру кода?

Tags: c++

Самостоятельно обучаюсь программированию. Сейчас пытаюсь решить задачу, найденную в интернете.
Что в моем коде неправильно? Думаю, я сделал много глупых ошибок, поэтому прошу не судить меня строго. При выполнении консоль пустая.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double p,a=p,y,x=0.1;
    while (x<=2*p)
    {if (x<=a)
    {   y=pow(cos(x-a),2)/a*sqrt(x);
        printf("\nx=%f\ty=%f",x,y);
        }

    else if(x>a)
    {   y=exp(-a*x)/log(x+a);
        printf("\nx=%f\ty=%f",x,y);
    }
        x=x+p/6;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо еще и указать эту задачу. Потому что если спросить - "я правильно выяснил, что ответ 8?", то если спрашивалось, чему равно 2*4, то да, а если 2*2 - то нет... Пока ваш грех виден в том, что вы сравниваете x со значением переменной p, которого нет (мусор, словом). Кстати, если отформатировать код - с ним будет **гораздо** легче работать...

Comment: Вычислить таблицу значений функции y для значений аргумента Х с шагом DX.
Хн=0.1
a=p
Шаг DX=p/6
Xk=2p
Y (если х<=a)= cos^2(x-a)/a*sqrt(x)
Y(если х>a)=exp(-ax)/ln(x+a)

Comment: Осталось выяснить, что такое p. Это 0? 100? 3.1415926?

Comment: А это в задаче не указано) А есть способ просто вывести буквенное значение в ответ? Например х=2Р У=1/5Р?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком ТЗ - вот ваше ХЗ:

```
int main()
{
    double p = 0.0;
    do {
        printf("Input p (> 0.1): ");
        scanf("%lf",&p);
    } while (p <= 0.1);

    for(double x = 0.1; x <= 2*p; x += p/6)
    {
        double y = (x <= p) ?
            cos(x-p)*cos(x-p)/p*sqrt(x)
            : exp(-p*x)/log(x+p);
        printf("%12.6lf   %12.6lf\n",x,y);
    }
}
```

P.S. Но вообще-то это какая-то чушь...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно на самую свою первую строку

```
double p,a=p,y,x=0.1;
```

значение p не присвоено. То есть, там мусор (любое абсолютно значение). Его присваиваете переменной a. Это уже лишено смысла - в а и так будет мусор.

Дальше

```
while (x<=2*p)
```

Это условие как известный кот может и выполнятся и нет. Дальше даже нет смысла обсуждать код - использование неинициализированной переменной - плохо и печально.

Поэтому, почитайте свое условие,  внимательно проставьте начальные значения всех переменных, напишите объявления в несколько строк, а не одним скопом и все будет ок.

И почитайте наконец [Зачем нужно обнуление переменных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155912/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/170022#170022)

Comment: Но в задаче Р и не указана...Т.е. невозможно сделать нормальный код с переменной без значения?

Comment: скорее всего ее надо ввести. Но для начала можно просто присвоить какое-то значение?