# Почему при компиляции кода выдает ошибку SigSegv?

Tags: c++

При компиляции моего кода выдает ошибку SigSegv.Чем это вызвано?Что нужно изменить,что бы ошибка пропала?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<conio.h >


int main() 
{
    const int n=20;  
    int i,massiv[i], Xmax=0, Nmax;
    printf("Spisok chisel v massive");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
     massiv[i]=(std::rand() % 200)-100;
        printf ("\nmassiv[%i]={%i}",i,massiv[i]);
    }


    //----------------------------


   for (int i=1; i<n;i++)
      if (massiv[i]<0 && massiv[i]> Xmax) //??? (massiv[i] > massiv[Nmax])
      {
      Xmax = massiv[i];
      Nmax = i;
  }
else;
    printf("Maximalvoe otritsatelnoe chislo");
    printf("Xmax=%i,Xmax");
    printf (" at index ");
    printf("Nmax=%i,Nmax");     
     getchar();
}
```

Вот второй код,все работает

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
     int i;
    const int n=20;  
    float result = 1.0;
    int massiv[n];
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
     massiv[i] = (std::rand() % 200)-100;
}
    for( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
    if(massiv[i] >1) result *= massiv[i]; 
    else;
}
printf("\nMassiv soderzhit dannie chisla");

    for( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {

        printf ("\nmassiv[%i]={%i}",i,massiv[i]);



    }
     printf("\nProizvedenie vseh polozhitelnih chisel massiva ravno  ")  ;

     printf("\nresult=%5.0f",result);

getchar();
}
```

Comment: вы обявили  massiv[i], а нужно   massiv[n]...

Comment: Почему? В цикле у меня меняется I,соотвественно и massiv[I]... Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: у вас обявлен также int i. уберите его

Comment: Я сейчас совсем запутался.Если я уберу i и оставлю просто massiv[n] т.е. massiv[20] то у меня не будет работать рандомизатор чисел...

Comment: Наверное, ошибка выдается все же не при компиляции, а при выполнении? :)

Comment: Я не уверен) В терминах еще путаюсь,извините)

Comment: @Alexey, i у вас обявлен в цикле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале читаете мой любимый вопрос - [Зачем нужно обнуление переменных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155912/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/170022#170022) и понимаете, что по умолчанию, значение переменных обычно не выставляется.

Когда Вы пишете `int i = 0;`, Вы можете быть уверенны в значении `i`. Но когда Вы пишете `int i;`, то значение `i` может быть произвольным (для программиста конечно,  для процессора оно абсолютно точное и определенное в данный момент времени).

Теперь рассмотрим вторую половинку квеста - `int massiv[i];` Тут припрятана одна интересная штука - [VLA](https://habr.com/post/195148/). Она нормально реализована только в gcc/clang и является особенностью си. Но не с++. Но почему то она осталась в плюсовой реализации, видимо лень было. Эта штука позволяет объявлять массив с размером, который определяется в процессе исполнения программы. И он выделяется на стеке. А стека обычно не много - 1мб в 32 битном режиме и 8мб на 64битном.

Складываем две половинки вместе. В переменной `i` какое то неизвестное число, и нам нужно на стеке выделить массив такого размера (в байтах это будет скорее всего в 4 раза больше). С очень большой вероятностью, переменная `i` будет содержать что то больше чем 256*1024. А может и отрицательное. И в этих случаях выделить память не выйдет и будет вышеуказанное падение.

Что же делать? самое простое - не писать странного кода и писать так как посоветовали уже - `int i,massiv[n]` - размер массива все таки должен быть константой (а visual studio компилятор Ваш код даже не скомпилит).

Или перестать писать на си (а он действительно написан на си) и начать писать на плюсах. Но это видимо в следующем семестре:)

Да, кстати, комбинация

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
```

немного тавтология - это один и тот же header, просто один сишный, другой - плюсовый.

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался,но осталась не могу кое что понять... Сначала обьявляется massiv[n]но после этого используется только massiv[I] и выводится тоже он.Это ведь вообще разные переменные должны быть?

Comment: при объявлении в квадратных скобках указывается размер. А при использовании  - указывается индекс элемента в массиве. Можно считать, что это просто омографы (имеют одинаковое написание, но разное значение).  Уточнение - `massiv[I]` выводит не массив, а один элемент с индексом `I` (поэтому там и цикл)

Answer (score 0):

Много ошибок у вас (в том числе и логические и эстетические), поэтому просто напишу, а вы сравните....

```
const int n=20;
int massiv[n], Xmax= std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
     Nmax = 0;
printf("Spisok chisel v massive");
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    massiv[i]=(rand() % 200)-100;
    printf ("\nmassiv[%i]={%i}",i,massiv[i]);
}


//----------------------------


for (int i=1; i<n;i++)
    if (massiv[i]<0 && massiv[i] > Xmax ) {
        Xmax =  massiv[i];
        Nmax = i;
    }
printf("\nMaximalvoe otritsatelnoe chislo  ");
printf("Xmax=%i,\n", Xmax);
printf (" at index  ");
printf("Nmax=%i ", Nmax);
```

P.S. когда вы обьявляете

```
const int n=20;  
int i,massiv[i], Xmax=0, Nmax;
```

то i  и Nmax  содержат мусор, и во всяком случаи ваш массив неизвестно какого размера будет...

Comment: Почему же? I в цикле приравнивается значение 0-19. Nmax в итоге будет равно индексу выбранного по условию массива...

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался,но осталась пара непонятных моментов.
1) Сначала обьявляется massiv[n]но после этого используется только massiv[I] и выводится тоже он.Это ведь 2 разных значения должно быть,или нет?
2) Что делает функция numeric_limits? Приравнивает Xmax к самому маленькому значению?Просто нигде не нашел подробной информации,только примеры,по которым ничего особо не понятно...

Comment: чтобы быть кратким,  std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), это минимальное значение типа  int.  В цикле  переменная i меняет свое значение от  0 до n, и используется каждое это значение, поэтому  в цикле    massiv[I]  ... а обьявляется  massiv[n], чтобы для массива резервировалось  место  для n  элементов.  Про   std::numeric_limits  есть много информации и в учебниках и в интернете, но если для вас это сложно, то можете просто   Xmax обьявить с каким то очень маленьким значением: например,  Xmax  = -99999999